# mklink Junction Point Link cannot create file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, mklink

I'm trying to create a .BAT file where it will create App Links and Web Links using MkLink but I can't seem to get it running.

[image]

```
@echo off
SET LINK_APPROOT=C:\Users\Intern\Desktop\debugprojects\GeneratedAppServer
SET LINK_WEBROOT=C:\Users\Intern\Desktop\debugprojects\GeneratedWebServer
SET TARGET_ROOT=C:\inetpub\wwwroot

SET WWWROOT_DIR=C:\inetpub\wwwroot
SET CURRENT_DIR=%~dp0

REM Creating App links
mklink /j %LINK_APPROOT%\GeneratedAppServer\commandline %TARGET_ROOT%\App\App_Code\commandline
mklink /j %LINK_APPROOT%\GeneratedAppServer\dbaccess %TARGET_ROOT%\App\App_Code\dbaccess
mklink /j %LINK_APPROOT%\GeneratedAppServer\entitydef %TARGET_ROOT%\App\App_Code\entitydef
mklink /j %LINK_APPROOT%\GeneratedAppServer\hub %TARGET_ROOT%\App\App_Code\hub
mklink /j %LINK_APPROOT%\GeneratedAppServer\lib %TARGET_ROOT%\App\App_Code\lib
mklink /j %LINK_APPROOT%\GeneratedAppServer\service %TARGET_ROOT%\App\App_Code\service

REM Creating Web links
mklink /j %LINK_WEBROOT%\GeneratedWebServer\entitydef %TARGET_ROOT%\Web\App_Code\entitydef
mklink /j %LINK_WEBROOT%\GeneratedWebServer\hub %TARGET_ROOT%\Web\App_Code\hub
mklink /j %LINK_WEBROOT%\GeneratedWebServer\lib %TARGET_ROOT%\Web\App_Code\lib
mklink /j %LINK_WEBROOT%\GeneratedWebServer\View_Code %TARGET_ROOT%\Web\App_Code\View_Code
mklink /j %LINK_WEBROOT%\GeneratedWebServer\web\App_Pages %TARGET_ROOT%\Web\App_Pages
mklink /j %LINK_WEBROOT%\GeneratedWebServer\web\Images %TARGET_ROOT%\Web\Images
mklink /j %LINK_WEBROOT%\GeneratedWebServer\web\Scripts %TARGET_ROOT%\Web\Scripts
mklink /j %LINK_WEBROOT%\GeneratedWebServer\web\WS %TARGET_ROOT%\Web\WS

pause
```

What should I change, or am I missing? I am new to create .bat file and using mklink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [`mklink` description](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)  or `mklink /?`:

```
==> mklink /?
Creates a symbolic link.

MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

        /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
                symbolic link.
        /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
        /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
        Link    specifies the new symbolic link name.
        Target  specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link refers to.
```

Both errors are related to the `Link` part of commands, see next example:

```
==> dir d:\bat\files\bub*| findstr /I "bub"
23.11.2015  17:57    <DIR>          bubu

==> mklink /J "D:\bat\files\bubu" "D:\test\a folder path"
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

==> mklink /J "D:\bat\filesNoFolder\bubu" "D:\test\a folder path"
The system cannot find the path specified.

==> mklink /J "D:\bat\files\bubux" "D:\test\a folder path\even if not exists"
Junction created for D:\bat\files\bubux <<===>> D:\test\a folder path\even if not exists

==> dir d:\bat\files\bub*| findstr /I "bub"
23.11.2015  17:57    <DIR>          bubu
27.12.2016  10:08    <JUNCTION>     bubux [D:\test\a folder path\even if not exists]

==>
```

Use `echo ON` to see exactly what happens.

BTW, the `%~dp0` and `%CD%` directories could differ:

- `%~dp0` = folder where a script resides
- `%CD%`  = current directory